# Is it possible for a set of random variables to each be highly correlated with another variable, but not highly correlated with each other?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, correlation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ and $Y$ be random variables. Is it possible for the $X_i$'s to all have a high magnitude of correlation against $Y$ (absolute value of Pearson's $r$), but not be strongly correlated with each other?

Comment: I assume you mean $X_i$ is correlated to $Y$ but not $X_j$ for all $i\neq j$. What about $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ independant, and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Clearly $X_i$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, and $X_i$ are independant thus uncorrelated. Is that enough to satisfy your conditions? What target exactly needs to be met for "highly correlated"?

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135196/2546) (reference included) that $d(X,Y)= \sqrt{1 - r_{X,Y}^2}$ , where $r$ is the correlation factor, is a proper distance.

Then, we can state

$$d(X_i,Y) \le \epsilon \implies d(X_i, X_j) \le 2 \epsilon$$

If all the correlations $({X_i,Y})$ are high, so that $|r_{X_i,Y}| \ge \rho \ge \sqrt{3/4} = 0.86660$ then we have the bound

$$ |r_{X_i,X_j}| \ge 2 \sqrt{\rho^2 -\frac34}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cor}{\operatorname{cor}}$
$$
\cor(A,C) \ge \cos\big( \arccos(\cor(A,B)) + \arccos(\cor(B,C)) \big)
$$

For example, if $\cor(A,B)=0.98$ and $\cor(B,C)=0.96$ then the two arccosines are
respectively about $ 11.47834^\circ $ and $16.26026^\circ,$ and their sum is about $27.73855^\circ,$ whose cosine is about $0.8850807,$ so $\cor(A,C)$ cannot be smaller than that.

If $\cor(A,B)<0$ then $\cor(-A,B)>0$ and all of the above applies.

Daniel T. Kaplan's book *Statistical Modeling: A Fresh Approach* is quite explicit about this.